# jQuery not working with SemanticUI and Electron.js

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, electron, semantic-ui

I've been trying to use Semantic UI in my HTML for an Electron app. I am able to load the elements, but I can't use jQuery for some reason. I've tried both my local jQuery copy:

`<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

and the CDN version:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

but none seem to work. I've tried doing simple things with jQuery but that still isn't working either. Any help would be appreciated. I would prefer to use my local copy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Title</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
      <!-- <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
         <a class="item">1</a>
      </div>

      <div class="pusher">
         <h1 class="asdf" id="asdf">Hello</h1>
      </div>


      <script>
         document.getElementById("asdf").innerHTML = "new1";
         $('#asdf').text("new2");
         $('#asdf').html("new2");
      </script>
      <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "isn't working?" What specifically is happening that's contrary to expectations? I'd be a helpful step if you open your developer tools for the Electron window so you can see network requests and console errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your `index.html`

```
  <head>
    <script>
      window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
    </script>
    ....
```

And `createBrowerWindow` with `nodeIntegration` at your `main.js`.

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you!